# How do I migrate startAllRoutes function from 2.23.2 to 3.1.0?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am migrating legacy source from 2.23.2 to 3.1.0.

My application starts all routes after route xml file is loaded.
To do start, I used below logic.

```
camelcontext.startAllRoutes();
```

But in camel 3.1.0, this function is deprecated.

If all routes is all started, how do I change upper logic?

Comment: I do not see that it is deprecated: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-base/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/engine/DefaultRouteController.java#L64

Comment: I use modelcamelcontext. But there is not startallroutes. How can I use routecontroller?

Comment: I found it. Thank you.